# Power latching circuit issue

Tags: power, mosfet, latching

I'm working on designing a circuit to latch power to an ATTINY85 when a button is pressed, then turn the power off when the button is held, but for some reason, the below schematic is not working. Does anyone have any ideas? When I load it Proteus, the 7805 is automatically providing 5 V without a button press.

[image]

Comment: "...7805 is automatically providing 5v...", does it work after that?  ie, is it just a power up issue?  Or does it not work at all?  And what is C2,Q3 doing?

Comment: The Q1 mosfet shouldn't allow any voltage to the 7805 until Q2 is flipped (the latch). C2, Q3 is "unlatch", Pressing the button should drain C2, once it's drained, Q2 will flip back and then the gate will close on the mosfet. That's my understanding anyway.

Comment: C2 Q3 isn't doing anything useful as drawn.  Something is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have positive feedback between Q1 and Q2. Leakage from Q1 can pass to the base of Q2, causing an increase in Gate-Source voltage, causing an increase in leakage.

At startup, if Q1 leaks 100nA, and we assume that 50% flows into Q2's base, Q2 produces 2uA, and a voltage drop of 0.2mV across R3. As long as that increases Q2's current by any amount it will feedback and eventually turn on.

It might also be that at power on the system settles to on. Your MOSFET is initially open, because when there's no voltage V<sub>GS</sub> = 0V, and it takes around 61ns for Q1 to turn off. Q2 has a BW of 100MHz (10ns period) so could reasonably turn on faster.

Similarly, any number of transients could turn Q2 on. When power or load is connected, for example, anything that causes an increase in Q1's base current, or an increase in the voltage drop across R3 could latch the system on.

You'd have to get a scope and have a look at exactly what was going on to be sure.
Your circuit, as many have pointed out, isn't going to work how you think it will. Charging C2 isn't really going to contribute anything, as it's not needed to maintain on-state, and indeed it won't be charged by pressing SW1. Pressing SW1 would discharge it if it was charged, but that won't impact the circuit.

For starters, Swap R4 so it connects the output of U1 with the base of Q2 (change resistance accordingly) that should get rid of your feedback loop so that the circuit won't start until your press SW1. I can't off the top of my head figure out how you'd get the same button to turn the circuit with the same button, but that should at least turn on when you want it.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what Q3 and C2 are doing, it makes no sense to me.

However, to address your question, I believe that capacitances in Q1 and Q2 are causing Q1's gate to remain low following application of power, long enough to cause it to stay latched on.

You can prevent this by attaching a small capacitance from Q2's base to ground, something like 1nF. That will keep Q2 switched off while the system settles down.